# Rest Assured - Response body verification

Tags: rest-assured, hamcrest

I have the below response and I need to validate the body.

**Json :**

```
[
   "Admin Login",
   "Admin Contact",
   "Administrator",
   "Ads-View"
]
```

**Code :**

```
@Test(groups = {"ITTest"})
public void testAdmin() 
{
    com.jayway.restassured.response.Response testAdminResponse = get("/Admin");
    testAdminResponse.then().assertThat().statusCode(200);
    testAdminResponse.then().assertThat().body("$",equalTo("["Admin Login", "Admin Contact", "Administrator", "Ads-View"]"));
}
```

I tried hamcrest matchers - equalTo, containsString, hasItems, hasItem but all in vain

How do I validate the body completely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to validate the response as a whole and if you know for certain that the response will be of the below format

> [
>          "Admin Login",
>          "Admin Contact",
>          "Administrator",
>          "Ads-View"
>       ]

Then you can, convert the response as a string and use Assert.assertEquals

```
Assert.assertEquals(**response**, "[\n" + 
        "   \"Admin Login\",\n" + 
        "   \"Admin Contact\",\n" + 
        "   \"Administrator\",\n" + 
        "   \"Ads-View\"\n" + 
        "]");
```

I ran it locally and it works fine for me

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/Admin";
String **response** = RestAssured.given().
when().get().then().extract().asString();
Assert.assertEquals(response, "");
System.out.println("Body is : " + response);
```

Comment: Final I did the same thing. I created a string which will be the response and did assertEquals, Then it worked fine. Thanks you for the help.